# How can I get reproducible results using keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Every time I run my model within the same environment I get the same results, the problem exists when I run the same code in a different environment, in terms of accuracy it is very similar but I'm trying to get the exact same training.

So far I have tried to seed everything

Seed value

```
seed_value= 42
```

1. Set `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value

   ```
   import os
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
   ```
2. Set `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value

   ```
   import random
   random.seed(seed_value)
   ```
3. Set `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value

   ```
   import numpy as np
   np.random.seed(seed_value)
   ```
4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)
   ```
5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session

   ```
   from keras import backend as K

   session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

   sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)

   tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)`
   ```

So at the moment I get the same results on the environment 1 every time I run the code, on environment 2 the same thing happens BUT the results from environment 1 are not equal to 2, any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed` to make almost any `Keras` program fully deterministic. For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed). Thanks!